# adding a hash to hash or symbol on the fly Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, symbols

I would like to know how to add a hash to hash on the fly
and increment the hashes on the inside.

```
words_to_scan.scan(/\w+|\?|\.|!|\,/).select do |aword|
  if words_from_file.has_key?(aword.to_sym)
      words_from_file[aword.to_sym]['pop'] += 1
  else
    words_from_file[aword.to_sym]['pop'] = 1
  end
end
```

i am trying to create something like

```
words_from_file = {:the => {'pop' => 3, 'positions' => [1,6,10]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words_from_file = {}
words_to_scan.scan(/\w+|\?|\.|!|\,/).select do |aword|
  words_from_file[aword.to_sym] ||= {} # declare hash if was not already declared 
  words_from_file[aword.to_sym]['pop'] ||= 0 # set pop if was not already set
  words_from_file[aword.to_sym]['pop'] += 1  # increment
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The default_proc of a Hash runs whenever a key is *not* found. Here it creates a new Hash as value for the new key:

```
words_from_file.default_proc = Proc.new{|h,k,v| h[k] = {'pop' => 0, 'positions' => []} }

words_to_scan.scan(/\w+|\?|\.|!|\,/).each do |aword|
  words_from_file[aword.to_sym]['pop'] += 1
end
```